# JavaFX Как обратится к TextArea в controller из другого метода?

Tags: javafx, textarea, controller

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста! Есть `controller` в котором есть `TextArea`:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public TextArea ta;
}
```

Как обратится к `TextArea` из другого класса? Как передать `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя должна быть ссылка на этот созданный контроллер, и либо ты делаешь

```
controller.ta // что плохо
```

либо ты создаешь метод ( в классе `Controller`), который принимает строку, и эту строку проставляешь в `TextArea` :

```
public void setTextToArea(String s) {
   this.ta.setText(s);
}
```